# Setting a has_one relation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-one

I can't figure out why this **doesn't** work:

```
home_team = Team.find_by_name! home_team["name"]
away_team = Team.find_by_name! away_team["name"]

fixture.home_team = home_team
fixture.away_team = away_team
```

but this **does**:

```
home_team = Team.find_by_name! home_team["name"]
away_team = Team.find_by_name! away_team["name"]

fixture.home_team_id = home_team.id
fixture.away_team_id = away_team.id
```

Fixture model:

```
class Fixture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :home_team, foreign_key: 'home_team_id', class_name: 'Team'
  has_one :away_team, foreign_key: 'away_team_id', class_name: 'Team'
  ...
end
```

I don't get any errors, and the row saves, but `home_team_id` and `away_team_id` are both `null`...

Can someone explain?

Comment: If your `Fixture` has the `home_team_id` and `away_team_id` you'd want to use `belongs_to` in there.

Comment: Ok, so yeh I changed the relation to belongs_to instead and it worked as expected. But I still don't understand why has_one worked one way and not the other?

Comment: It worked in your second example because you are setting the attributes directly, while in your first example it failed because the association was not correctly set up.

Comment: Yeh I feel stupid. Thanks for the response!